# How to apply a workflow from import to processing on 100 data files all at once?

Tags: r, dataframe, import, workflow

How would I apply a workflow from start to finish sort of like a for loop in R except with all the data files in my working directory?

My workflow has the following components

```r
# Load libraries 
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Import data 
File_1 <- as.data.frame(read.table("file_1.bed", header = FALSE, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = ""))

# Separate one of the columns into 2 new columns 
filtered_File_1 <- separate(data = File_1, col = V3, into = c("end position", "Methylation"), sep = "\\|")

# Change NAN values to zero 
new_File_1 <- filtered_File_1[- grep("NAN", filtered_File_1$Methylation), ]
filtered_File_1$Methylation[filtered_File_1$Methylation == "NAN"] <- '0'

# Change values into numeric
filtered_File_1$Methylation <- as.numeric(as.character(filtered_File_1$Methylation))

# Add New column
filtered_File_1$ID <- c("1")

# Take the average of numerical values
Average <- filtered_File_1% >% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), list(mean)))
```

Essentially how would I iterate the above process over and over again for all 100 datafiles? The reason is that individually its a bit tedious to copy and paste the lines of code and it'll make the R script very long as well. I know how to use lapply for lists but what would allow for something much more complicated involving file imports and processing? There must be an easier way.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the output to be? If you have a list of file paths to files (see `as.list(list.files(pattern = ".bed"))` a lapply with the processing steps wrapped in a function seems sufficient here.

Comment: The output would be a processed data frame ready for plotting. Each CSV would go through the pipeline with the raw data files entering and the processed ones leaving.

Answer (score 2):

If the files fit in working memory, we can use a `lapply` to achieve the same as a for-loop, or since the post uses `tidyverse`, `purrr::map`. This results in a list of data frames with summary statistics returned by function `get_means`.

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- as.list(list.files(pattern = ".bed")) %>%
  set_names(nm = sub(pattern = ".bed$", "", .))

get_means <- function(x){
  as.data.frame(read.table(x)) %>%
    separate(col = V3, into = c("end position", "Methylation"), sep = "\\|") %>%
    mutate(Methylation = ifelse(Methylation == "NAN", "0", Methylation),
           Methylation = as.numeric(Methylation)) %>%
    group_by(V1) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), list(mean)))
}

lapply(files, get_means) # map(files, get_means)
```

or in a for-loop:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".bed") %>%
  set_names(sub(pattern = ".bed$", "", .))

result <- vector(mode = "list", length(files)) %>% #initialize list
  set_names(names(files))

for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  result[[i]] <- get_means(files[i])
}
```

To write new files of summary statistics to disk directly, say with name *filename_stats.csv*:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".bed") %>%
  set_names(sub(pattern = ".bed$", "", .))

new_file_names <- paste0(names(files), "_stats.csv")

for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  write_csv(get_means(files[i]), file = new_file_names[i])
}
```

**Example:**
Consider the following reproducible example - using `mtcars` and `iris` where we can create a named list with summary statistics:

```
write.csv(mtcars, file = "mtcars.csv")
write.csv(iris, file = "iris.csv")

files <- as.list(list.files(pattern = ".csv")) %>%
  set_names(nm = sub(pattern = ".csv$", "", .))

lapply(files, \(x){
  read.csv(x) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))
})

$iris
     X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1 75.5     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333

$mtcars
       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear   carb
1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125
```

I'm not sure what the `new_File_1` in the original code is supposed to do as it is not used.

Comment: I really liked your use of a function to get it all done and apply it across all files. However, the files are quite large so is there a way to edit it to get each file's output as a new separate file or data frame? Since it's for eventual plotting of the data.

Comment: @user305902 For that purpose I added a for-loop approach, as a list of summary statistics shouldn't take up much memory. However, I've now updated it with a method to write to disk directly.